# Is "0X"-prefixed hexadecimal integer literal in Spanner SQL legal?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

The documentation says in [§ "Integer Literals"](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/lexical#integer-literals):

> Integer literals are either a sequence of decimal digits (0–9) or a hexadecimal value that is prefixed with "0x".

When this sentence is correct, Spanner SQL doesn't accept "0X" (not "0x", "X" is upper case of "x") prefixed integer literal, however Spanner seems to accept "0X"-prefixed hexadecimal number literal in fact.

See https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1544#issuecomment-523763115.

I'm confusing that this is expected behavior in Spanner, or not.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation in googlesql says only 0x is supported for hex int literals but we actually also support 0X. We will update the docs to reflect that and avoid confusion.